# Vagrant: Am I setting up the triangle topology correctly?

Tags: networking, vagrant

I am trying to set up a triangle triangle topology with vagrant as follows:

```
  B
 / \
A---C
```

But need to be sure if my setting is correct. Each node is supposed to have two network interfaces, which I see when I run `ifconfig`, (shows `enp0s3` = vagrant default; `enp0s8` = eth1 ; `enp0s9` = eth2 ; `lo` = local loopback).

However, when running a traceroute from A to C with link(A,C) broken after `sudo ifdown` command, I still see `treceroute` output only shows C's IP on a single line and does not show B's IP. This is what got me wondering if my vagrant setup is correct or not.

I have tried with different netmask values but still get 1 hop on the `traceroute` from A to C with `link(A,C)=down`.

I am running on latest Virtualbox coming out of ppa package (5.2.x) and vagrant version 2.2.x. The host is running 18.04 and the guests for the VMs are running 16.04.

```
...
...
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  ...
  ...
  config.vm.define "A" do |a|
    a.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.18.3",
      netmask: "27",
      virtualbox__intnet: true
    a.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.18.8",
      netmask: "29",
      virtualbox__intnet: true
    a.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2024"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "B" do |b|
    b.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.18.4",
      netmask: "27",
      virtualbox__intnet: true
    b.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.18.5",
      netmask: "28",
      virtualbox__intnet: true
    b.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2024"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "C" do |c|
    c.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.18.6",
      netmask: "28",
      virtualbox__intnet: true
    c.vm.network "private_network",
      ip: "192.168.18.7",
      netmask: "29",
      virtualbox__intnet: true
    c.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2024"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "1"]
    end
  end
end
...
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
virtualbox__intnet: true
```

This places all six network interfaces on the same internal network.

To create three separate subnets, specify internal network by name, such as:

```
virtualbox__intnet: "netAB"
virtualbox__intnet: "netBC"
virtualbox__intnet: "netCA"
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem of the subnet issue.